# Chrome browser unique identification

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am trying to build an app for chrome based on my api. Is there a unique id in chrome browser which i can store to identify the chrome browser on which the app is being installed. Maybe something like getting the signed in Google account from the browser or any other string unique to every Google chrome installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unique installation? Google is actively trying to *prevent* fingerprinting (e.g. `chrome.usb` API is not allowed to enumerate devices, etc.), so - no perfectly reliable methods. You can try collecting various pieces of info and try to fingerprint, but it's not recommended.

You can request access to the Google credentials for people signed into Chrome if you ask for `"identity"` and `"identity.email"` permissions, with [`chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo):

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(info) {
  // Use info.id, it's a unique token that's bound to the account
  //   but does not expose email (better for privacy)
});
```

You can also use [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) to keep some kind of ID token. You can randomly generate it or, better, generate it on your API side on request.

If you keep it in `local` storage area - it will be kept per browser profile, in `sync` - it will replicate across all signed-in instances if sync is enabled. Note that both will be wiped if the user uninstalls your app.